# change .ribbonname property on open

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

**Context:**
I have an Access database application that was built in Access 2k. I have a custom ribbon built that I am playing around with, and I also have some user "security" in this app.

When a report opens, I want to check the username and switch to a different ribbon for specific users. I would think that this code would work:

**The Code:**

```vb
If GetUserName() = "admin" Then
    Me.Report.RibbonName = "CustomPrintPreview"
Else
    Me.Report.RibbonName = "MSToolbar1"
End If
```

**The Problem:**
This code seems to execute (and it's not doing `On Error Resume Next`).  However when the open event ends, the report opens with no data (when there should be data). If I remove this if block, it runs fine aside from setting the correct ribbon. I should mention that if I manually set the RibbonName property for the report, both ribbons work fine, so it is not a problem with the ribbons themselves.

I'm currently using access 2007, but this will be deployed for 2010 versions as well. Does anyone know what's going on here?